# How can I communicate between a hardware interface service and a web-page?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, signalr, communication

I have an application that runs as a website (not locally hosted) on a kiosk and I'd like to improve the usability of the login page by tapping an RFID tag against a reader on the kiosk and populating the username box on the login page with the value read from the tag.

I've written a windows service that monitors the com port and reads the RFID tag but I'm not sure how to communicate this data to the webpage on screen.  What I'm currently investigating is having a centralised "device hub" api and transmitting the value from the RFID reader service to the hub via SignalR and then relaying it onwards to the webpage again via SignalR.

I'm using asp.net core for both the kiosk website and the proposed "device hub" and I've already got Identity Server 4 in use that I'm planning to use to authenticate the components here although I think I might run into some issues with cross-domain authentication I'm hoping they're surmountable.

My question is this - is this the right strategy for communicating like this?

Before I go too far down this rabbit hole is this technique my best option (using SignalR to "bounce" the message off a device hub and then forward it to the website login page)?

[image: A simplified sequence diagram outlining what I have in mind]

Comment: Just to clarify a little, this system runs on a kiosk that runs on windows - the RFID reading service is a windows service that runs on that kiosk attached to RFID reader hardware built into the kiosk.  The "app" is a website displayed full screen on the kiosk.

Comment: There are a million ways to do this, so this question will probably be considered off-topic here sadly. I'd say though that your proposal seems like a sensible one.

Comment: Yeah I had a look around first but couldn't see any exact question for this scenario, most seemed related to the website and service both being hosted on the same machine and just chatting between them but in my scenario the website is hosted remotely while the RFID reading service is hosted locally and I just want to get the message from the service to the webpage.  I think SignalR is the tool for the job but this is out of my comfort zone so just wanted to see if anybody yelled "For the love of all that is holy don't do that!" before I started work on it.

Comment: The root issue is that the hardware device and browser have no way of directly communicating, so you need to add something that allows them to communicate indirectly. It could be node.js, it could be a custom implementation using web sockets/RPC/whatever, but if you're using an MS tech stack, SignalR is probably the simplest solution.